# Python local variable in func

Tags: python

```
def test(a):
    if a>1:
        x=0
    elif a<1:
        y=1
    else:
        x=2
    print(x)
    return 0
```

Why `test(2)` is ok but `test(0)` will raise the following error?

`local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

I guess when `test(2)` `x` was defined, but run `test(0)` `x` was not defined, but also want to know more about the cause

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much answered it yourself. If `a` is 0, then the `elif a<1` is true, so only `y` gets defined.

Answer (score 0):

Because with `test(0)` the function `test()` only sets variable `y` but not variable `x`, and yet you are unconditionally printing `x` in the end, causing an `UnboundLocalError` exception.

Since you are not using `y` at all, it appears that it is actually a typo, and that you mean to set `x` to `1` there, so change your code to:

```
def test(a):
    if a>1:
        x=0
    elif a<1:
        x=1
    else:
        x=2
    print(x)
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not initiating your variables in the function.

When the you have test(0), the second condition `elif a<1:    y=1` is satisfied. but then you try to print x which is not even defined and the interpreter doesn't know what it is.

```
def test(a):
...:     if a>1:
...:         x=0
...:     elif a<1:
...:         x=1
...:     else:
...:         x=2
...:     print(x)
...:     return 0
```

This will not raise the error.